# Comparison of two elements in different array

Tags: python, arrays, csv, cs50

**My problem:**
I am trying to compare two elements from two different arrays but the operator is not working.

**Code Snippet in question:**

```
for i in range(row_length):
    print(f"ss_record: {ss_record[i]}")
    print(f"row: {row[i + 1]}")
                
    #THIS IF STATEMENT IS NOT WORKING
    if ss_record[i] == row[i + 1]:
        count += 1
    #print()
    #print(f"row length: {row_length}")
    #print(f"count: {count}")
    if count == row_length:
        print(row[0])
        exit(0)
```

**What I have done:** I tried to print the value of `ss_record` and `row` before it runs through the `if` statement but when it matches, `count` doesn't increase. I tried storing the value of `row` in a new array but it bugs out and only store the array length and first 2 value of row and repeats those values every next instance.

**What I think the issue:** I think the issue with my code is that row is being read from a `CSV` file and is not being converted into an integer as a result, it appears they are the same but one is an integer while the other is a string.

**Entire Code:**

```
import csv
import sys
import re
from cs50 import get_string
from sys import argv

def main():
    line_count = 0
    if len(argv) != 3:
        print("missing command-line argument")
        exit(1)
    
    with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as database:
        sequence = open(sys.argv[2], 'r')
        string = sequence.read()
        reader = csv.reader(database, delimiter = ',')

        for row in reader:
            if line_count == 0:
                row_length = len(row) - 1
                ss_record = [row_length]
                for i in range(row_length):
                    ss_record.append(ss_count(string, row[i + 1], len(row[i + 1])))
        
                ss_record.pop(0)
                line_count = 1
            
            else:
                count = 0
                for i in range(row_length):
                    print(f"ss_record: {ss_record[i]}")
                    print(f"row: {row[i + 1]}")
                    
                    #THIS IF STATEMENT IS NOT WORKING
                    if ss_record[i] == row[i + 1]:
                        count += 1
                if count == row_length:
                    print(row[0])
                    exit(0)
  
 
#ss_count mean the # of times the substring appear in the string
def ss_count(string, substring, length):
    count = 1
    record = 0
    pos_array = []

    for m in re.finditer(substring, string):
        pos_array.append(m.start())
    
    for i in range(len(pos_array) - 1):
        if pos_array[i + 1] - pos_array[i] == length:
                count += 1
        else:
            if count > record:   
                record = count
            count = 1
    
    if count > record:   
        record = count
    
    return record
main()
```

**Values to use to reproduce issue:**

> sequence (this is a text file) = AAGGTAAGTTTAGAATATAAAAGGTGAGTTAAATAGAATAGGTTAAAATTAAAGGAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCAGAAAAGAGTAAATAGTTAAAGAGTAAGATATTGAATTAATGGAAAATATTGTTGGGGAAAGGAGGGATAGAAGG

> substring (this is a csv file) =
> name,AGATC,AATG,TATC
> Alice,2,8,3
> Bob,4,1,5
> Charlie,3,2,5

**Gist of the CSV file:**
The numbers beside Alice means how many times a substring(STR/Short Tandem Repeat) appears in a row in the string(DNA sequence). In this string, AGATC appears 4 times in a row, AATG appears 1 time in a row, and TATC appears 5 times in a row. For this DNA sequence, it matches Bob and he outputted as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were right, when you compare `ss_record[i] == row[i + 1]:` there is a type problem, the numbers of ss_record are integers while the *numbers* of the row are strings. You may acknowledge the issue by printing both `ss_record` and `row`:

```
print("ss_record: {}".format(ss_record)) -> ss_record: [4, 1, 5]
print("row: {}".format(row)) -> row: ['Alice', '2', '8', '3']
```

In order for the snippet to work you just need to change the comparison to

```
ss_record[i] == int(row[i + 1])
```

That said, I feel the code is quite complex for the task. The string class implements a `count` method that returns the number of non-overlapping occurrences of a given substring. Also, since the code it's working in an item basis and relies heavily in index manipulations the iteration logic is hard to follow (IMO). Here's my approach to the problem:

```
import csv

def match_user(dna_file, user_csv):
    with open(dna_file, 'r') as r:
        dna_seq = r.readline()

    with open(user_csv, 'r') as r:
        reader = csv.reader(r)
        rows = list(reader)

    target_substrings = rows[0][1:]
    users = rows[1:]

    num_matches = [dna_seq.count(target) for target in target_substrings]
    for user in users:
        user_matches = [int(x) for x in user[1:]]
        if user_matches == num_matches:
            return user[0]

    return "Not found"
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: I don't understand how this logic works: `[dna_seq.count(target) for target in target_substrings]`. I get this is pythonic but how does it work.

Comment: @manav-dubey This syntax is called [List Comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). In essence it'a a way of mixing iteration and computation, slightly reminding math [set-builder notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation). An english translation would be: `For every STR check in the dna sequence how many times it appears and save these results into a list`